# In kubernetes cluster, kafka service not showing an external IP, though I used LoadBalancer type

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I followed the steps from this guide to create a kafka pod:
https://dzone.com/articles/ultimate-guide-to-installing-kafka-docker-on-kuber

Though I used LoadBalancer type for kafka-service (as said in the guide), I don't get an external IP for kafka-service:
[image]

On kubernetes dashboards kafka-service is shown as running.

Comment: What is the installation type of your kubernetes? is it managed? which provider?

Comment: Where is the kubernetes hosted?

Answer (score 1):

The `LoadBalancer` service and `Ingress` are only available to Kubernetes if you are using any cloud provider, like: GCP, AWS, Azure etc... **It's not supported by default for bare-metal** implementations.

But, if you are running kubernetes bare-metal, **alternatively**, you can use [MetaLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to *enable* the service `LoadBalancer` type and `ingress`.

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. The implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.

**For minikube**

[On minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service), the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the minikube service command.

Run the following command:

`minikube service hello-node`

**Or** you can [enable the nginx-ingress addon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#enable-addons) if you want to to create an ingress:

`minikube addons enable ingress`